# i cant install scikit_learn library

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy

When I want to install scikit-learn I have this error can someone help me?

```
C:\>pip install scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  .....
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
    Running setup.py install for scikit-learn ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys,
 setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\H00MAN\\AppData\\Local\\Tem
p\\pip-install-9cwhjbqg\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\H
00MAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9cwhjbqg\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"';f
=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r
\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
install --record 'C:\Users\H00MAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4f1gt5bz\install
-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\H00MAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9cwhjbqg\scikit-lea
rn\
```

When I install it this error apeared. I install numpy,scipy and joblib and I dont khow what is my problem

Comment: Try using whl, wheel file. You can't download offline wheel file corresponding to ur env from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/